# Torrent tracker software for a Microsoft environment

Tags: windows, bittorrent

I am 100% Microsoft on my home server.  I'd like to add a tracker to disseminate some applications I've written.  I run Server 2012, my website is written in C# and my back end is SQL Server, so as you can see I'm centered around Microsoft products.  I'm trying to find a legitimate tracker that I can integrate into my website.  I know that you can create private torrents using uTorrent, but I'd like to have a proper tracker along the lines of DimeADozen or ThePirateBay; one where people can post comments under the torrent.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure  what's your exact requirement, do you want a BitTorrent *tracker* software or do you want some kind of website front-end?

Comment: I'm looking for the whole thing, soup to nuts.  I did notice that some torrent sites simply use a vBulliten board, which might work fine too, although I do like the look and feel of DimeADozen, and I like the way you can see stats like who's seeding and what their seed percentage is.  Truth is, I've never looked into running one so I'm not entirely sure *what* I'm looking for, I just know I'm looking to run one on a very small scale.